# Android google app stopped

Tags: android

HI i am trying to run a simple app in android that shows a Google map but whenever i try to run in on emulator it shows `unfortunately gmap has stopped`. Please help me out.
here is my code

**gmap manifest**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.gmap"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

 <uses-feature
      android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
      android:required="true"/>

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.gmap.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**main activity**:

```
package com.example.gmap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
public class MainActivity extends MapActivity 

{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}



@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

}
```

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
 <com.google.android.maps.MapView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map_view"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:enabled="true"
  android:apiKey="AIzaSyBS0vnUbvFlLYpqI9Q1IcAwh0mPuDNG07o" />
```

**log cat errors:**

```
03-06 10:01:05.059: E/Trace(1934): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

03-06 10:01:06.337: E/AndroidRuntime(1934): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

03-06 10:01:06.337: E/AndroidRuntime(1934): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gmap/com.example.gmap.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.gmap.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.gmap-1.apk

03-06 10:01:06.337: E/AndroidRuntime(1934):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)

03-06 10:01:06.337: E/AndroidRuntime(1934):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)

03-06 10:01:06.337: E/AndroidRuntime(1934):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)

03-06 10:01:06.337: E/AndroidRuntime(1934):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)

03-06 10:01:06.337: E/AndroidRuntime(1934):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

03-06 10:01:06.337: E/AndroidRuntime(1934):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

03-06 10:01:06.337: E/AndroidRuntime(1934):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)

03-06 10:01:06.337: E/AndroidRuntime(1934):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

03-06 10:01:06.337: E/AndroidRuntime(1934):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-06 10:01:06.337: E/AndroidRuntime(1934):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)

03-06 10:01:06.337: E/AndroidRuntime(1934):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)

03-06 10:01:06.337: E/AndroidRuntime(1934):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

03-06 10:01:06.337: E/AndroidRuntime(1934): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.gmap.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.gmap-1.apk

03-06 10:01:06.337: E/AndroidRuntime(1934):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)

03-06 10:01:06.337: E/AndroidRuntime(1934):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)

03-06 10:01:06.337: E/AndroidRuntime(1934):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)

03-06 10:01:06.337: E/AndroidRuntime(1934):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)

03-06 10:01:06.337: E/AndroidRuntime(1934):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)

03-06 10:01:06.337: E/AndroidRuntime(1934):     ... 11 more

03-06 10:07:29.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2071): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

03-06 10:07:29.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2071): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gmap/com.example.gmap.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.gmap.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.gmap-1.apk

03-06 10:07:29.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2071):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)

03-06 10:07:29.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2071):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)

03-06 10:07:29.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2071):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)

03-06 10:07:29.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2071):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)

03-06 10:07:29.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2071):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

03-06 10:07:29.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2071):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

03-06 10:07:29.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2071):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)

03-06 10:07:29.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2071):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

03-06 10:07:29.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2071):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

03-06 10:07:29.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2071):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)

03-06 10:07:29.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2071):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)

03-06 10:07:29.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2071):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

03-06 10:07:29.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2071): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.gmap.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.gmap-1.apk

03-06 10:07:29.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2071):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)

03-06 10:07:29.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2071):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)


03-06 10:07:29.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2071):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)

03-06 10:07:29.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2071):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)

03-06 10:07:29.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2071):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)

03-06 10:07:29.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2071):     ... 11 more


03-06 10:10:37.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2399): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

03-06 10:10:37.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2399): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gmap/com.example.gmap.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.gmap.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.gmap-1.apk

03-06 10:10:37.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)

03-06 10:10:37.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)

03-06 10:10:37.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)

03-06 10:10:37.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)

03-06 10:10:37.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

03-06 10:10:37.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

03-06 10:10:37.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)

03-06 10:10:37.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

03-06 10:10:37.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-06 10:10:37.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)

03-06 10:10:37.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)

03-06 10:10:37.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

03-06 10:10:37.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2399): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.gmap.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.gmap-1.apk

03-06 10:10:37.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)

03-06 10:10:37.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)

03-06 10:10:37.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)

03-06 10:10:37.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)

03-06 10:10:37.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)

03-06 10:10:37.347: E/AndroidRuntime(2399):     ... 11 more

03-06 10:15:48.487: E/Trace(2492): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

03-06 10:15:49.018: E/AndroidRuntime(2492): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

03-06 10:15:49.018: E/AndroidRuntime(2492): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity 
ComponentInfo{com.example.gmap/com.example.gmap.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.gmap.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.gmap-1.apk

03-06 10:15:49.018: E/AndroidRuntime(2492):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)

03-06 10:15:49.018: E/AndroidRuntime(2492):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)

03-06 10:15:49.018: E/AndroidRuntime(2492):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)

03-06 10:15:49.018: E/AndroidRuntime(2492):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)

03-06 10:15:49.018: E/AndroidRuntime(2492):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

03-06 10:15:49.018: E/AndroidRuntime(2492):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

03-06 10:15:49.018: E/AndroidRuntime(2492):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)

03-06 10:15:49.018: E/AndroidRuntime(2492):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

03-06 10:15:49.018: E/AndroidRuntime(2492):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

03-06 10:15:49.018: E/AndroidRuntime(2492):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)

03-06 10:15:49.018: E/AndroidRuntime(2492):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)

03-06 10:15:49.018: E/AndroidRuntime(2492):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-06 10:15:49.018: E/AndroidRuntime(2492): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.gmap.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.gmap-1.apk

03-06 10:15:49.018: E/AndroidRuntime(2492):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
03-06 10:15:49.018: E/AndroidRuntime(2492):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
03-06 10:15:49.018: E/AndroidRuntime(2492):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
03-06 10:15:49.018: E/AndroidRuntime(2492):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)

03-06 10:15:49.018: E/AndroidRuntime(2492):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)

03-06 10:15:49.018: E/AndroidRuntime(2492):     ... 11 more

03-06 10:16:57.220: E/AndroidRuntime(2520): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 10:16:57.220: E/AndroidRuntime(2520): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gmap/com.example.gmap.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.gmap.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.gmap-1.apk

03-06 10:16:57.220: E/AndroidRuntime(2520):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)

03-06 10:16:57.220: E/AndroidRuntime(2520):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)

03-06 10:16:57.220: E/AndroidRuntime(2520):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)

03-06 10:16:57.220: E/AndroidRuntime(2520):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)

03-06 10:16:57.220: E/AndroidRuntime(2520):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

03-06 10:16:57.220: E/AndroidRuntime(2520):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

03-06 10:16:57.220: E/AndroidRuntime(2520):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)

03-06 10:16:57.220: E/AndroidRuntime(2520):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

03-06 10:16:57.220: E/AndroidRuntime(2520):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

03-06 10:16:57.220: E/AndroidRuntime(2520):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)

03-06 10:16:57.220: E/AndroidRuntime(2520):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)

03-06 10:16:57.220: E/AndroidRuntime(2520):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

03-06 10:16:57.220: E/AndroidRuntime(2520): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.gmap.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.gmap-1.apk

03-06 10:16:57.220: E/AndroidRuntime(2520):     at 
dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)

03-06 10:16:57.220: E/AndroidRuntime(2520):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)

03-06 10:16:57.220: E/AndroidRuntime(2520):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
03-06 10:16:57.220: E/AndroidRuntime(2520):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)

03-06 10:16:57.220: E/AndroidRuntime(2520):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)

03-06 10:16:57.220: E/AndroidRuntime(2520):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>`
tag in your manifest file.

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
    android:name="com.example.gmap.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
</application>
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Tried this, still not working. if you can suggest any other solution, help me to rectify errors

Answer (score 0):

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
   <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="apikey"/>
         <activity
            android:name="com.example.mappro.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    </application>
```

You are missing:

```
 <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="api key"/>'
```